# Water pressure builds up slower then normal

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, pump

We had no water for about three days due to a leaking valve, but after we fixed the valve and start the pump the pressure tank takes more then 10 minutes to fill up(usually it’s less then a minute). We replaced the check valve thinking it was allowing water to back flow but it didn’t help. The water pressure does not drop after the pump turns off and there doesn’t seems to be any leak or any blockage since we are getting water in the house. We also check the air pressure of the pressure tank which is 2 psi under the turn on pressure.

Comment: You may have debris in the plumbing preventing the flow, I have seen Teflon tape and plastic debris wedge at valves, the valve worked fine but the blockage restricted the flow. The other possibility is a split line below the check valve. The pressure is holding above the check valve but when the pump is running the split leaks back into the well.

Comment: do you have a submersible pump or a jet pump with a single or double pipe?